# Unity changing gameobject's transform position once game starts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character selection screen, when a certain button is pressed the assigned character will slide into view. Unfortunately for one of my character's they transform position seems to change putting them higher, etc making them not appear on the game screen. I'm not sure why as both character's have the same components and no where in code tells them to change position. The only script they have works as slide animation to make seem as though they glide into view instead of just appear. (attached below)

If I change the character's avatar int he animator to the same as the other character's then their position will be correct but then they will not do any animations.

- Winter is the working GameObject.
- Eunha is the one that changes position. Before the game starts Eunha's transform position is the same as Winter's shown in the Inspector.

[image: hierachy]
[image: winter]
[image: eunha]

````
    private Vector3 startPosition;
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        finalPosition = transform.position;
        startPosition = finalPosition - transform.right * 5.0f;
    }
   
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, finalPosition, 0.1f);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        transform.position = startPosition;
    } ```
````

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the hierarchy?

Comment: @The-Anonymous i added the image to my original post if that helps!

Comment: The position can be controlled by the animation. Does the object move to the desired position if you disable the animator?

Comment: ah yes if i disbale the animator in the inspector then she will also move to correct position. Does that mean I somehow need to change the position of the animation? Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

The codeing order seems to be problem. I recommend using 2 empty objects to determine location. This script is more efficient and reliable.

```
    public Transform startPosition; // place on start position
    public Transform endPosition; // place on shifted position

    public float duration = 1f;

    public void OnEnable() => StartCoroutine(Shift()); 

    public IEnumerator Shift()
    {
        var shiftProgress = 0f;
        
        while (shiftProgress < 1)
        {
            shiftProgress += Time.deltaTime/duration;

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition.position, endPosition.position, shiftProgress);
            
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for help Kiyan unfortunately this didn't fix my issue with one of my characters having a higher position!

Comment: @Karina If so. I think the problem is not with the code and maybe the model pivot or some other part has a problem.